# How to know drag-drop is outside of browser-window?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I try to check if a draggable element is dropped outside the browser-window.
Is that possible?
I do not know how to thet that info out of the event of ondragend.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo (txt, e)
{
    console.log (txt, e);
}
</script>

<div style="border:2px red solid; width: 200px;" draggable="true"  
  ondragstart="foo('start', event)"
  ondragend="foo('end', event)">
  abc<br>xzy
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've posted a similar question before I found yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066685/how-to-decide-whether-a-dragdrop-operation-points-to-somewhere-outside-the-brow. Did you find an answer yet? Currently my only approach is to use the `drop` event of some background element to store the fact that it has taken place _inside_ the browser and use `dragend` and `drop` together somehow. That's ugly and doesn't work with `drag` or `dragover` events..